# Truncated Message due to "TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'" (in raspberry pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, arm, protocol-buffers, raspbian

I am receiving these errors only in Raspberry Pis:  `"TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'"`

- Python 3.5.3
- Raspbian Stretch 9.1
- The following packages:
  grpcio (1.6.3)
  grpcio-reflection (1.6.3)
  grpcio-tools (1.6.3)

test.proto (very simple):

```
syntax = "proto3";

package bug;

message Foo
{
    string field1 = 1;
}
```

and the Python code:

```
from test_pb2 import Foo

EXPECTED = bytearray(b'\n\x04AAAA')
foo = Foo()
foo.field1 = 'AAAA'
print(foo)

data = foo.SerializeToString()
print(data)
assert (data == EXPECTED)

foo.ParseFromString(EXPECTED)
assert (foo.field1 == 'AAAA')
```

The deserialization only fails in Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu is fine):

> field1: "AAAA"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py",
>   line 1069, in MergeFromString
>       if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py",
>   line 1092, in InternalParse
>       field_decoder, field_desc = decoders_by_tag.get(tag_bytes, (None, None)) TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 13, in
>   
>       foo.ParseFromString(REF)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/message.py",
>   line 185, in ParseFromString
>       self.MergeFromString(serialized)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py",
>   line 1075, in MergeFromString
>       raise message_mod.DecodeError('Truncated message.') google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem in the Raspberry Pi.

The issue was that when running in the Pi deserialize fails for `bytearray`, however, if the data is passed as `bytes` things work well.

So my current workaround is to do something like:

```
foo.ParseFromString( bytes(EXPECTED) )
```

I am still not sure why the same problem does not happen in desktops. What I have noticed is that when debugging in desktops, `foo.ParseFromString` is shown as `<built-in method ParseFromString of Foo object at 0x7fedcc0b3fa8>` so I suppose that there is some native optimization in desktops that is not available when running in the Pi.

When I have a little more time I will try to investigate a little more on how protobuf is deployed. Maybe in the meantime someone can share some details.